# Persmissions Cordova iPhone plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, permissions, media, phonegap-plugins

I made an app where the users record voice and send the voice to each other. The app is using the media plugin to cordova, and when you press the record button on iPhone an alert pops up and ask the user for their permission to record audio. This happens of course only once, but how can I remove it so it never happens? I have noticed that a lot of users tend to click on no, and then they are not able to record anything if they not delete the app and download it again.

Comment: You can't remove that. Even the default iOS camera asks you that when you record video for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the user permission alert box. Best way to handle this is to check the status, if user has disabled then show alert with instructions how to enable from iPhone -> Settings -> ...

Not sure if the plugin you are using supports status, with native code you can do detect if user has not given permission and display alert.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I make this question stay open to see if some phonegap people have any answer